# How do I switch windows using ALT+ TAB in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window, application-switcher

I have opened 2 new windows of Chrome in Ubuntu. How do I select them using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>? Every time I need to use mouse for this. Is there any way to do like in Windows?